# How to solve ESLint error `package should be listed in dependencies, not devDependencies`

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint

I'm trying to lint my React+Typescript project properly (with ESLint). I have a component in which i'm importing `useParams` hook from `react-router`.

```js
import { useParams } from 'react-router';
```

ESLint is giving me error on that line

```
ESLint: '@types/react-router' should be listed in the project's dependencies, not devDependencies.(import/no-extraneous-dependencies)
```

As i guess `@types/react-router` is not needed in resulting build, because browsers don't understand TypeScript. So i have 2 questions here:

- why rule says `@types/react-router` should be listed in dependencies and not in devDependencies?
- should i indeed move `@types/react-router` to dependencies?
- Can i just disable that rule? If so, how can i understand when i can disable ESLint rules and when i should resolve ESLint error?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A dependency is a library that a project needs to function effectively. DevDependencies are the packages a developer needs during development.

react-router will be used in your app and not as a dev dependency so try to install it with

```
npm install react-router --save
//OR
yarn install react-router --save
```

instead of

```
npm install react-router --save -dev
```

Comment: It's a good try, but this question was specifically about the `@types/react-router` package, not the `react-router` package itself. In other words, the types definition from DefinitivelyTyped.

Comment: Yes. GregL is right - my question was about `@types/react-router`